# Get order value on success page for conversions

Tags: bigcartel

I'm setting up some conversion javascript on a BigCartel store.

I'd like to get the order value in a variable, e.g.

```
var conv_total = "[order value here]";
```

And I can't find an appropriate variable from BigCartel. Anyone know the proper bit of code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a way to modify the success page to include any kind of order details, so adding your own conversion code to include order values isn't possible. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on BigCartel earlier and I had noticed there is no particular variable of order total for confirmation page. still if you have some idea about jQuery/javaScript you can customize conversion code to add order value because total amount is appearing on confirmation page. if you need more assistant let me know I can try to sort this issue for you. To contact leave a message on http://www.notesonclick.com